# best way to automatically convert microsoft office documents

Tags: ms-office

What is the best way to convert Microsoft Office documents automatically on a server? We need to convert lots of such documents automatically to PDF files. Currently we use PDFCreator with an OLE script, but it is a fragile process since Microsoft Office popups keeps interrupting the flow.

I have tried OpenOffice, but it is not good enough at converting Microsoft Office documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by 'automatically', but try Google Documents. You can upload .doc files in bulk to be converted to google's format. From there, you can export (in bulk) to PDF.

To use Google Docs, get a gmail account (or google apps account) and go to docs.google.com

Comment: So store the data on google's servers? Not advisable in many cases, I guess. Also, won't this slow down the automated conversion process? Its better to get this done locally, although I am not sure how. There seem to be a few shareware scripts to do this, but they are definitely not more reliable than pdfcreator.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, the documents contain personal information in some cases so we can't send them to google.

Comment: definitely depends on your specific case. this is probably the simplest way to do it, but not ideal on a larger scale or if there is any hesitation about giving the data to google.

Answer (score 2):

We've used the Oracle OutsideIn technology (formerly known as "Stellant") to do conversions of Office documents to XML. It was 99% effective, but there was the occasional document that would confound it.

http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/embedded/025613.htm

They appear to have a PDF Converter component, but I have not used it.

OutsideIn is pretty pricey. They are targeting the enterprise customer.

--

There's also KeyView from Autonomy, but we have not used that either. Looks like they do not have a direct to pdf option, but they do go to html directly.

http://www.autonomy.com/content/Products/idol-modules-connectors/index.en.html